# How to do Multiple Joins with Merge Into?

Tags: sql-server, join, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I have these 3 tables

- Company

  - id
- Branch

  - id
- Items

  - id
  - StockNumber

Company can have many branches and a branch can have many items.

Now I got to write a query that will either insert or update an item depending on conditions.

Some items can only appear once in the company and some items can appear in each branch.

The problem for me is the ones that can only appear once in the company. I think I am going to need to basically join all these tables together and do a check but I don't know how to do this join in a "Merge Into Sp"

I made a table type that looks like this

```
CREATE TYPE ItemTableType AS TABLE   
( 
  BranchId INT,
  CompanyId INT
  Description nvarchar(Max),
  StockNumber: INT  
);
```

In my code I can pass the companyId into my tabletype

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Usp_upsert @Source ItemTableType readonly 
AS 
    MERGE INTO items AS Target 
    using @Source AS Source 
    ON 
     // need to somehow look at the companyId so I can then find the right record reguardlesss of which branch it sits in.
     Targert.CompanyId = source.CompanyId // can't do this just like this as Item doesn not have reference to company table.
     Target.StockNumber = source.StockNumber
    WHEN matched THEN 
      // update
    WHEN NOT matched BY target THEN 
      // insert
```

Edit

Sample Data

```
Company
Id Name
1   'A'
2  'B'

Branch
Id name CompanyId
1   'A.1'  1
2   'A.2'  1
3   'B.1'  2
4  'B.2'   3

Item
Id Name StockNumber BranchId
1  Wrench  12345      1
2  Wrench  12345      3
3  Hammer  484814     2
4  Hammer 85285825    4
```

Now a bulk data is going to be sent into this SP via C# code and looks something like this

```
 DataTable myTable = ...;  

  // Define the INSERT-SELECT statement.  
  string sqlInsert = "dbo.usp_InsertTvp"  

  // Configure the command and parameter.  
  SqlCommand mergeCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlInsert, connection);  
  mergeCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  SqlParameter tvpParam = mergeCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source", myTable);  
  tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  
  tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.SourceTableType";  

  // Execute the command.  
  insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Now say when an import of records come in and the data looks like this

```
Wrench (Name),  12345 (StockNumber), 2 (BranchId..they are switching the branch of this item to another branch)
```

If I would just send this in then if I used BranchId + Stocknumber nothing would be updated and a new record would be inserted what would be wrong as now 2 branches have the same item(based on stockNumber)

If I would just use StockNumber then these 2 records would be updated.

```
1  Wrench  12345      1
2  Wrench  12345      3
```

Which is wrong as these records are from 2 different companies. Thus I need to also use the companyId, thus I need to also check the companyId.

EDIT (from comments):

I think I have to do Target Dot something. This is what I came up with so far:

```
MERGE INTO Items AS Target 
using @Source AS Source 
ON Source.CompanyID=(
  SELECT TOP 1 Companies.Id 
  FROM Branches 
  INNER JOIN Companies 
    ON Branches.CompanyId = Companies.Id 
  INNER JOIN InventoryItems 
    ON Branches.Id = Target.BranchId 
  where Companies.Id = Source.CompanyId 
  and StockNumber = Source.StockNumber
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The description of what you need to do is too vague for me to be specific, but you can simply do a query with JOINs as your source.  I like to put it in a CTE to make it pretty like so:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT query with JOINS)
MERGE INTO items AS Target 
using cte AS Source 
ON
```

EDIT:   To also do a JOIN on the Target (`items`) you need to do it in the ON conditions:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT query with JOINS)
MERGE INTO items AS Target 
using cte AS Source 
ON Source.CompanyID=(
  SELECT TOP 1 CompanyId 
  FROM TableWithCompanyId 
  JOIN Target 
    ON JoinCondition=true
 )...
```

I know yours involves two tables to get from items to company, but the example above shows you the technique that I believe you are missing.

EDIT 2, based on latest attempt:

Try it this way:

```
MERGE INTO Items AS Target 
using @Source AS Source 
ON Source.CompanyID=(
  SELECT TOP 1 Companies.Id 
  FROM Branches 
  INNER JOIN Companies 
    ON Branches.CompanyId = Companies.Id 
  WHERE Branches.Id = Target.BranchId 
)
and Target.StockNumber = Source.StockNumber
```

Comment: Sorry what is vague? so am I not using the parameters now from the type table?

Comment: Ok, I updated my question with an example hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly you also need to know how to do a JOIN in the Target.   That's a little more involved as you must put it in the ON condition of the MERGE.   I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, I am trying to apply what you have suggested, I am just bit confused if there are now 2 sources(one for the table type and one for this join? If so how do I specify both)?

Comment: Ok, I got to play around with it more. Do you think doing this will slow down the code? I am using this code and sending in a datatable that has 1000 records, I am not sure if they get handled one by one or in bulk.

Comment: It does slow the code down.  If the columns joining the three tables are indexed, it will be a minimal slowdown.   1000 records is no big deal at all to SQL Server.   When you get closer to 100,000 records, you might notice a difference.

Comment: Ok that's good to hear, what still gets me in your code. Is that right now @@source in my code is holding all the parameters from ItemTableType but in your code it seems like source is now the query of all the joins. So I am not sure how they both fit in together. Like I guess the paramters coming in would be used in the join, but how do I access them if they are not in the @@source

Comment: Yes, you can ignore that part if you want to keep using your ItemTableType.   Since that table already has `CompanyID`, then you only need to implement the bottom part of my code.

Comment: Ok, so I did this   Source.CompanyID=(SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Companies JOIN Target  ON Id=Source.CompanyId)  but what is Target? I get an error on it.

Comment: Yea, but I think I have to do Target Dot something. This is what I came up with so far 
 ` MERGE INTO Items AS Target
    using @Source AS Source 
    ON 
  Source.CompanyID=(SELECT TOP 1 Companies.Id 
FROM            Branches INNER JOIN
                         Companies ON Branches.CompanyId = Companies.Id INNER JOIN
                         InventoryItems ON Branches.Id = Target.BranchId
   where Companies.Id = Source.CompanyId and StockNumber = Source.StockNumber)`